# Problem from Spivak Calculus from the chapter Limits.(Chapter 5 Problem - 18)

Tags: limits

The problem is as follows:

"Prove that if the limit $f(x)$ as $x$ tends to $a$ is $L$, then there exists an $m\gt0$ and $M$ such that $|f(x)|\lt M$ whenever $0\lt|x-a|\lt m$.

Hint : Why does it suffice to prove $1-L\lt f(x)\lt1+L$ whenever $0\lt|x-a|\lt m$?"

Now, from the hint I understand that if I keep $\epsilon=1$ for some $m>0$, I will get $1-L< f(x)< 1+L$ for $0<|x-a|< m$ and then I can select $M$ such that $M>1+L$ and $-M<1-L$ so that $-M< f(x)< M$. Hence $|f(x)|< M$. But I think this is not a rigorous solution. Can anyone provide me a rigorous solution?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Answer (score 1):

You can slightly improve your choice of $M$ by making it very explicit. Pick 
$$
M = 2 + |L|.
$$
Then
$$
L \le |L| = M - 2 < M
$$
and 
$$
-L \le |L| = M - 2 < M.
$$

But frankly, your proof was just fine as-is. It might be clearer if you wrote it as a two-column proof, so you'd have to be careful to get everything in order; I'd recommend you try that as a way of improving your exposition.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is fine. You can end the proof by observing that if $M >|L|+1$ then we have both $M  >L+1$ and $-M <1-L$.