# Prove that if $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x) = L $, then there is a number $\delta > 0 $ and a number M such that $ |f(x)| < M $ if $ 0 < |x-a| < \delta $

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

This is the exercise from M. Spivak's "Calculus": Chapter 5, Problem 18. I saw a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3339979/problem-from-spivak-calculus-from-the-chapter-limits-chapter-5-problem-18) but I think there is a mistake in the question and not all sub-questions are addressed. The problem states:

> Prove that if $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x) = L $, then there is a number $\delta > 0 $ and a number M such that $ |f(x)| < M $ if $ 0 < |x-a| < \delta $ (What does it mean pictorially?.
> Hint: Why does it suffice to prove that $L-1 < f(x) < L + 1$ for $0<|x-a|<\delta$?

So, for $\epsilon > 0 $ we have:
$$
L-\epsilon < f(x) < L + \epsilon
$$

Now, I understand why we have this expression. However, I am confused when we then proceed to take $-M < L - \epsilon$ and $M > L + \epsilon$ so that we get $|f(x)| < M$. Specifically, I don't understand what this M is ( is this some gap between the L and f(x) where we can find some value $|f(x)|<M$ ? And what does it mean pictorially? Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3339979/problem-from-spivak-calculus-from-the-chapter-limits-chapter-5-problem-18?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Confirm that the following is obvious and does not require an explicit proof under normal circumstances : if $a, b$ are two real numbers then there is a real number  $M>0$ such that $-M<a, b<M$.